# With Wordpress in Maintenance Mode, how do we exclude the wp-login.php page?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, twig, timber

So we added a custom maintenance page to our custom wordpress theme using ACF - but we somehow have to exclude the **wp-login.php** page or we won't be able to login to our website if Maintenance is on, any suggestions on how we would do this? Here is the code we have so far:

```
/////////////  Wordpress Maintenance Mode  ///////////

function maintenance_mode() {
    $context = Timber::get_context();
    Timber::render('maintenance.twig', $context);
    die();
}

$config = get_field('website', 'option');
if($config["status"]) {
    add_filter( 'wp_die_handler', '_custom_wp_die_handler' );
}else {
    if(!is_user_logged_in() && !is_admin()) {
        maintenance_mode();
    }

}

function _custom_wp_die_handler( $message, $title = '', $args = array() ) {
    maintenance_mode();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [$wp->request](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/274572/193479) you should be able to add an exclusion for the [wp-login](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_login_url/) page to your `if(!is_user_logged_in() && !is_admin()) {` statement to prevent the code from loading there.

You also need to use home_url( $wp-request ) inside a function call.  The code for this would be like this here:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'maintenance_mode_logic');
function maintenance_mode_logic() {
    global $wp;
    $config = get_field('website', 'option');
    if($config["status"] == 1) {
        //echo 'hello';
        //exit();
        add_filter( 'wp_die_handler', '_custom_wp_die_handler' );
    }else {
        if(!is_user_logged_in() && !is_admin() && home_url( $wp->request ) != wp_login_url()) {
            maintenance_mode();
        }
     
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quickreply! How would that look in the updated code, I am still pretty green at php. ~ thanks!  `if(!is_user_logged_in() && !is_admin()) && wp-login.php` ??

Comment: Something like this:
``if(!is_user_logged_in() && !is_admin() && home_url( $wp->request ) != wp_login_url()) { `` - note that you need the line `global $wp;` before this statement in the code.

Comment: thanks again - I did try the code just like this: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ESxPAHmV) but its not doing anything for me yet? Would you care to paste the entire code as its supposed to be in your answer? Will accept it as soon as its working! ~ Thank-you.

Comment: This is a funny one, and it's actually alluded to in one of the comments in the page I linked to (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274569/how-to-get-url-of-current-page-displayed) - "My issue was that I was including the code in functions.php 'naked,' i.e. not in any function that is attached to a hook. So your code was returning the URL of the homepage, regardless of the page that was displayed in my browser" - I'll edit my answer